# Understanding SVG query-string parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters, svg, query-string

I created an SVG file that I intend to use as a background image in CSS.  I want to be able to change the fill color in the SVG using a query-string parameter, like so:

```css
#rect     { background-image: url( 'rect.svg' ); }
#rect.red { background-image: url( 'rect.svg?color=red' ); }
```

As I understand, using a script tag in the SVG, I am able to get the `color` parameter and update the fill color. Here is an example SVG:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DDTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" />

    <script>
    <![CDATA[
        var params = { };
        location.href.split( '?' )[1].split( '&' ).forEach(
            function( i )
            {
                params[ i.split( '=' )[0] ] = i.split( '=' )[1];
            }
        );

        if( params.color )
        {
            var rect = document.getElementsByTagName( "rect" )[0];
            rect.setAttribute( "fill", params.color );
        }
    ]]>
    </script>
</svg>
```

Going to the file directly, or using an object tag seems to work, but for CSS background images or img tags, the color parameter is ignored.

I'm not exactly sure what is going on here, and I was hoping that there would be an explanation or alternative solution to what I'm trying to accomplish (preferably without resorting to server-side processing).

Here is a jsFiddle showing the different render methods: http://jsfiddle.net/ehb7S/

Comment: javascript is disabled when SVG is used either as a CSS background image or in an image tag.

Comment: Ahh, that explains why it doesn't work.  I'll leave this open in case there are any other clever solutions to passing parameters to the SVG via CSS, but it looks like I may be out of luck on this.

Comment: why not use some js outside the svg?

Comment: @mihai, if you can explain to me how to manipulate the CSS background SVG from outside JavaScript, that would be helpful.

Comment: yeah, I've been trying to figure it out...but it's either not possible, or non-trivial :)

Comment: JFTR: There’s a [proposal to pass CSS variables](https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/svg-params/) and an oldish [Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/) for `<object>` parameters and URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up created a server-side solution that allows me to inject the color fill into the SVG file. Essentially, I redirect all SVG requests to a PHP file that does the following on them:

```
$filename = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];

$svg = simplexml_load_file( $filename );
if( isset( $_GET['color'] ) )
{
    $svg->path->addAttribute( 'fill', '#' . $_GET['color'] );
}

header( "Content-type: image/svg+xml" );
echo $svg->asXML( );
```

Obviously, there's a little more to it than that, what with handling caching and such, but that's the meat-n-potatoes. Might want to check if the `fill` attribute already exists, as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an inline SVG that is hidden, change that and dynamically encode it as a data URL that you put into the `background-image` property.  Your HTML could look like:

```
<div id="backgroundContainer" style="display:none">
    <svg width="100px" height="100px" id="backgroundSvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="green"/>
    </svg>
</div>

<div id="divWithBackground" onclick="changeBackground(event)">
    Click to change background SVG to random color
</div>
```

and your JavaScript like

```
changeBackground = function(event) {
  var backgroundSvg = document.getElementById("backgroundSvg");
  var backgroundContainer = document.getElementById("backgroundContainer");
  backgroundSvg.getElementsByTagName("circle")[0].setAttribute(
    "fill",
    ["red","green","blue","black"][Math.floor(4*Math.random())]
  );
  event.target.setAttribute(
    "style",
    "background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml,"
    + encodeURI(backgroundContainer.innerHTML)
    + ")"
  );
}
```

See the [proof of concept on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTYdL/).